# Inside spring-boot--application.yml- what can be the replacement for colon?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

application.yml

```
Pensions : Workplace-DPO: ashishkumar@gmail.com
```

I want `Pensions : Workplace-DPO` to be as key , but its treating `DC Pensions` to be as key .

Quotes and square breakets didnt work for me. As an additional info-
I am fetching the value like this.

```
@Value("${Properties.Pensions : workplace-DPO}")
private String PWDPOM;
```

Do i need to change something here too?

Comment: You can't (shouldn't?) have spaces in yaml keys, anyway, but try to put square brackets around the key

Comment: Square Brackets did not work for me.@OneCricketeer

Comment: Why do you need colons, and spaces in your keys? Can't you just rename it? And yes `Properties.` prefix is not correct in the Value annotation

Comment: If you want to use spaces in a key, it can only be done inside a Map object - See docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding

Comment: @OneCricketeer, this is already there in the front end and cant rename it, though I will suggest my team for it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that since this yaml file is not a front end property file. You simply rename the property here, then fix the naming wherever you want to use that value. You can't get the key easily at runtime, anyway

Answer (score 0):

Include Key with quotes

```yaml
"LGIMDC Pensions: Workplace-DPO" : ashishkumar@gmail.com
```

Comment: Quotes did not working for me @Kirill Vizniuk